# Compute interval overlap percentage between different sources

Tags: r, dataframe, overlap

I have a dataframe containing intervals coming from different sources (A, B, C). I would like to compute pairewise overlap percentage between the interval of each sources. I wrote these following command lines. I was wondering if there is an easier/faster way to do that (my data are bigger than this example) and a way to make this more adaptable if I have a fourth source to include.

```
data=data.frame(StartA=c(134000,765888,243634,576098,398776,128598,NA), StopA=c(181654,842465, 244377, 582626,  399102, 129893, NA),
                StartB=c(134023,765880,243634,576098,NA,128598,849356), StopB=c(181654,842465, 244352, 582626,  NA, 129893, 868654),
                StartC=c(132065,NA,NA,592626,398776,128698,867656), StopC=c(191604,NA, NA, 593391,  399102, 129993, 868654))

data
   StartA  StopA StartB  StopB StartC  StopC
1 134000 181654 134023 181654 132065 191604
2 765888 842465 765880 842465     NA     NA
3 243634 244377 243634 244352     NA     NA
4 576098 582626 576098 582626 592626 593391
5 398776 399102     NA     NA 398776 399102
6 128598 129893 128598 129893 128698 129993
7     NA     NA 849356 868654 867656 868654

# For loop to compute each overlap for each row
#################################################
data$overlap_reciproq_AB=NA
data$overlap_reciproq_BC=NA
data$overlap_reciproq_AC=NA

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {

# overlap A vs B 
  
  if(!is.na(data$StartA[i]) & !is.na(data$StopA[i]) & !is.na(data$StartB[i]) & !is.na(data$StopB[i])) {
  overlapAB = max(0, as.numeric(min(data$StopA[i],data$StopB[i]))-as.numeric(max(data$StartA[i], data$StartB[i])))
  overlap_A_B = overlapAB / (data$StopA[i] -  data$StartA[i]) *100
  overlap_B_A = overlapAB / (data$StopB[i] -  data$StartB[i]) *100
  data$overlap_reciproq_AB[i] = min(overlap_A_B, overlap_B_A)
  }

  # overlap A vs C 
  
  if(!is.na(data$StartA[i]) & !is.na(data$StopA[i]) & !is.na(data$StartC[i]) & !is.na(data$StopC[i])) {
    overlapAC = max(0, as.numeric(min(data$StopA[i],data$StopC[i]))-as.numeric(max(data$StartA[i], data$StartC[i])))
    overlap_A_C = overlapAC / (data$StopA[i] -  data$StartA[i]) *100
    overlap_C_A = overlapAC / (data$StopC[i] -  data$StartC[i]) *100
    data$overlap_reciproq_AC[i] = min(overlap_A_C, overlap_C_A)
  
  }
  
  # overlap B vs C 
  
  if(!is.na(data$StartC[i]) & !is.na(data$StopC[i]) & !is.na(data$StartB[i]) & !is.na(data$StopB[i])) {
    overlapBC = max(0, as.numeric(min(data$StopB[i],data$StopC[i]))-as.numeric(max(data$StartB[i], data$StartC[i])))
    overlap_B_C = overlapBC / (data$StopB[i] -  data$StartB[i]) *100
    overlap_C_B = overlapBC / (data$StopC[i] -  data$StartC[i]) *100
    data$overlap_reciproq_BC[i] = min(overlap_B_C, overlap_C_B)
    
  }
}


# Output
#############################

  StartA  StopA StartB  StopB StartC  StopC overlap_reciproq_AB overlap_reciproq_BC overlap_reciproq_AC
1 134000 181654 134023 181654 132065 191604            99.95174            79.99966            79.99966
2 765888 842465 765880 842465     NA     NA            99.98955                  NA                  NA
3 243634 244377 243634 244352     NA     NA            96.63526                  NA                  NA
4 576098 582626 576098 582626 592626 593391           100.00000             0.00000             0.00000
5 398776 399102     NA     NA 398776 399102                  NA                  NA           100.00000
6 128598 129893 128598 129893 128698 129993           100.00000            92.27799            92.27799
7     NA     NA 849356 868654 867656 868654                  NA             5.17152                  NA
```

Comment: Percentages need a base. Should the base be the latter one? E.g. if we compare `A` and `B`, then `B` builds the base?

Comment: Actually, I would like to compute both and then take the minimum

Comment: I cannot think of an application where this would be appropriate.

Comment: I want to compare the overlap coming from different sources in order to see if they can be considered as the same event. If A overlap on 90% on B but B overlap on only 20% on A I don't want to consider them as the same. If the mimim is 90% it means that A on B and B on A overlap with at least 90% and I may want to consider them as a same event. (I simplified and the 90% may not be the threshold that I will use but this summarize the idea).

Comment: Your code for calculating `overlap_C_A` is using `overlapAB`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach which should scale to larger data sets and more sources uses `foverlaps` from the `data.table` package.  Note the ordering of the overlap columns is alphabetical in the final output.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

data=data.table(
  StartA=c(134000,765888,243634,576098,398776,128598,NA), 
  StopA=c(181654,842465, 244377, 582626,  399102, 129893, NA),
  StartB=c(134023,765880,243634,576098,NA,128598,849356), 
  StopB=c(181654,842465, 244352, 582626,  NA, 129893, 868654),
  StartC=c(132065,NA,NA,592626,398776,128698,867656), 
  StopC=c(191604,NA, NA, 593391,  399102, 129993, 868654))

# Convert to the appropriate format for foverlaps
dt <- melt(data, variable.factor = FALSE)
dt[, type := substr(variable, nchar(variable), nchar(variable))]
dt[, event := substr(variable, 1, nchar(variable) - 1)]
dt[, index := 1:.N, by = variable]

dt_wide <- dcast(dt[!is.na(value)], 
                 type + index ~ event, 
                 value.var = 'value',
                 fun.aggregate = mean)
setkey(dt_wide, Start, Stop)

# Calculate the overlaps
olap <- foverlaps(dt_wide, dt_wide)
olap <- olap[!(type == i.type & index == i.index) & type < i.type]

olap[, overlap := pmin(Stop, i.Stop) - pmax(Start, i.Start)]
olap[, dir := paste0(type, i.type)]
olap[, dir_prop := overlap/(Stop - Start)]
olap[, rev_dir := paste0(i.type, type)]
olap[, rev_dir_prop := overlap/(i.Stop - i.Start)]

# Calculate the final percentages
olap[, min_overlap := 100*pmin(dir_prop, rev_dir_prop)]

# Restructure to the output format in the question
index_data <- dcast(dt, 
                    index ~ type + event, 
                    value.var = 'value',
                    fun.aggregate = mean)
overlaps <- dcast(olap, index ~ dir, value.var = 'min_overlap') %>%
  setnames(., names(.), paste0('overlap_reciproq_', names(.)))
out <- overlaps[index_data, on = .(overlap_reciproq_index = index)]
setcolorder(out, setdiff(names(index_data), 'index'))

# Delete the extra index columns.
out[, overlap_reciproq_index := NULL]

   A_Start A_Stop B_Start B_Stop C_Start C_Stop overlap_reciproq_AB overlap_reciproq_AC overlap_reciproq_BC
     <num>  <num>   <num>  <num>   <num>  <num>               <num>               <num>               <num>
1:  134000 181654  134023 181654  132065 191604            99.95174            80.03829            79.99966
2:  765888 842465  765880 842465      NA     NA            99.98955                  NA                  NA
3:  243634 244377  243634 244352      NA     NA            96.63526                  NA                  NA
4:  576098 582626  576098 582626  592626 593391           100.00000                  NA                  NA
5:  398776 399102      NA     NA  398776 399102                  NA           100.00000                  NA
6:  128598 129893  128598 129893  128698 129993           100.00000            92.27799            92.27799
7:      NA     NA  849356 868654  867656 868654                  NA                  NA             5.17152
```